# p:remoteCommand JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource

Tags: jsf, primefaces, remotecommand

On a program I'm working on, at a certain point, after a certain event happens "work1Complete" I need to update a specific page component.

In order to do that, I only found the `<p:remoteCommand>` tag. I use it like so:

```
<p:remoteCommand id="updater" name="updater" update="updatedList" action="#{getUpdates.getUpdates()}" actionListener="#{getUpdates.updateSearchParam}" />
```

Then I call the function that it stores in the window object using:

```
window.updater({
    "updateString" : updateString
});
```

Without me searching, the only information I have is this:

> WARNING:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, /[].xhtml.

After some research in the executions, I was able to determine that getUpdates() is, somehow, being executed 13 times and updateSearchParam() is being executed 2 times.

getUpdates() receives void and returns an Iterable.
updateSearchParam() receives void and returns void.
updatedList is never updated.
Using the browser console, I don't see the information I gave it (that js object above) in the urlencoded request it does to the server.

I'm using primefaces 4.0 (with all its dependencies) with no other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear with your question?

If you mean that you need to perform an action after a certain event is triggered, you can have a boolean method in your backing bean that sets to true when the event is completed and then render the component based on your boolean result.

eg:

```
public class MyBean
{
    public boolean isTrue()
      {
        if(abc.getVal()
         {
           return true;
         }
        return false;
      }
}
```

xhtml

```
<h:outputLabel styleClass="formLabel" value="abc" rendered="#{myBean.true}" />
```

Comment: I don't get your answer. The event happens in the DOM. When that event happens, I need to update the contents of the component with the id="updatedList"

Answer (score 0):

change the your web.xml file like below code

web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Production</param-value></context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but now it's too late and I don't have the environment to try it anymore.